# Connect New Server to Static IP and To DNS Server

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, dns, network-interface

I have a strange setup. I have drawn a pretty crude diagram so it may be easier to explain.

[image]

Usually, all the new servers we add just go into the HPC cluster and we assign an IP address through our main DNS server.

MyMainServer is the host to all other computers. For instance you have to ssh into that server, before you can ssh into anything on the HPC cluster. That is pretty simple.

I now added a new server with it's own static IP using the interface em1. It works great if I don't connect p5P1. However, I still want to mount the storage array and be able to get onto nodes on the HPC server so I thought I would also connect that computer to MyMainServer through the p5p1 interface (those are 10 GB/s cards). However, ssh stops working when I connect p5p1. That is, it only works if I first ssh into MyMainServer, then ssh MyServer. It is still registering the correct IP address, but for some reason it wants to go through MyMainServer. Is there anyway to be able to still connect to the Storage Arrays through the 10 GB/s p5p1 interface and be able to have my primary IP be through em1?

MyServer is using Centos7, MyMainServer is using Ubuntu 14.04 Server. Both are DELL R720.

-J

Comment: PS, if anyone has any suggestions to how I should title this question, please let me know. I'm not really trying to connect it to a DNS server, I'm just trying to get to the storage array that is behind a pseudofirewall

Comment: Please provide the routing tables from a working server, and the new one you're setting up. route -n will display this infomation in an easy to read format.

Comment: If your diagram is accurate, you should be overhauling your setup. EM1 on mymainserver should not be both world facing and forwarding packets for your HPC cluster - this is insecure and most likely breaks routing and is the source of your problem.  In addition to the routing tables, you should also provide the IP addresses assigned to each Interface.  You need to assign IP addresses in a seperate subnet on p5p1 - I suspect you are assigning IP's in the same subnet and this is breaking your routing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check route table on your new server and make sure that your default route goes through em interface.